# Transform ODE to State-Space

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations, transformation, control-theory

Im currently training to transform ODEs into State-Space Form.

For ODEs in the Form of:

$\dfrac{d^n y}{dt^n}+a_{n-1}\dfrac{d^{n-1}y}{dt^{n-1}}+...+a_1\dfrac{dy}{dt}+a_0y=b_0\cdot u(t)$

there is no problem. But Im stucked with ODEs which have other forms.
For example:

$a_3\dfrac{d^3 y}{dt^3}+a_1\dfrac{dy}{dt}+a_0y=b_0\cdot u(t).$

My first attempt was to isolate the highest Derivative:

$\dfrac{d^3 y}{dt^3} = \dfrac{1}{a_3}\left(-a_0 y-a_1\dot y+b_0u(t)\right)$

Defining: $x_1=y, x_2=\dot y$ but from now on, I dont know any further..

Thanks for Help!

Edit:

Im trying it:

Defining: $x_1=y, x_2=\dot y,x_3=\ddot y$.

Assume:

$\dot x_1 = \dot y = x_2\\\dot x_2 = \ddot y = x_3\\\dot x_3 = \dddot y =\dfrac{1}{a_3}\left(-a_0 y-a_1 \dot y+b_0u(t)\right)=\dfrac{1}{a_3}\left(-a_0x_1-a_1x_2+b_0u(t)\right)$

So the State-Space Representation would be:

$\begin{bmatrix}
\dot x_1\\
\dot x_2\\
\dot x_3
\end{bmatrix}=\begin{bmatrix}
0 & 1 & 0\\
0 & 0 & 1\\
-\dfrac{a_0}{a_3} & -\dfrac{a_1}{a_3} & 0\end{bmatrix}\cdot\begin{bmatrix}
x_1\\
x_2\\
x_3
\end{bmatrix}+\begin{bmatrix}
0\\
0\\
\dfrac{b_0}{a_3}
\end{bmatrix}\cdot u(t)$

Is that right?

Comment: Perhaps there's a mistake in your post somewhere, but it seems like your example is in the form you give, just with $a_2=0$.

Comment: This is correct. For linear ODE's of the form you presented, the state space is quite trivial to obtain, since you will always obtain the controllable canonical form. Maybe one addition is the output equation, $y=x_1 = [ 1,0,0] x$. One other comment: If you put a $(t)$ after $u$, you also should at all the other timesignals :P